# Reading writes of child process from parent process

Tags: c, fork

In the following code, I am forking 5 times to create 5 child process each of which receives 
a string from parent process and the child process writes `child-i` back to the parent process 
where `i` is the loop counter in the for loop of child process. When I run this program I 
only see `child-0` and then the program hangs.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int num_processes = 5;
    int pipefd[2 * num_processes][2];
    pid_t cpid;
    char buf;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * num_processes; i++)
    {
        if (pipe(pipefd[i]) == -1)
        {
            perror("pipe");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_processes; i++)
    {
        cpid = fork();

        if (cpid == -1)
        {
            perror("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (cpid == 0)
        {                        /* Child reads from pipe */
            close(pipefd[i][1]); /* Close unused write end */

            while (read(pipefd[i][0], &buf, 1) > 0)
            {
            }
            char buf[12];
            snprintf(buf, 12, "child-%d", i);
            write(pipefd[num_processes + i][1], buf, strlen(buf));
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
            close(pipefd[i][0]);
            close(pipefd[num_processes + i][0]);
            break;
        }
        else
        { /* Parent writes argv[1] to pipe */
            /* Close unused read end */
            write(pipefd[i][1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
            close(pipefd[i][1]); /* Reader will see EOF */
            wait(NULL);          /* Wait for child */
            char buf;
            while (read(pipefd[num_processes + i][0], &buf, 1) > 0)
            {
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, 1);
            }
            close(pipefd[num_processes + i][0]);
        }
    }
    _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: It is dangerous for the parent to wait for the child to terminate before consuming its output from the pipe.  It shouldn't be an issue for the volume of data involved here, but for large enough data that will deadlock the two processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run this program I
> only see `child-0` and then the program hangs.

Yes, because the parent waits indefinitely to read more data from `pipefd[num_processes + i][0]`.  Consider this:

> ```
>             while (read(pipefd[num_processes + i][0], &buf, 1) > 0)
> ```

Judging by other parts of your code, you seem to appreciate that a process will not see EOF on reading from a pipe until the write end is closed, but perhaps you don't recognize that *all handles* on the write end need to be closed before the underlying open file description is closed.  Or perhaps you simply aren't taking into account that the parent process has a copy of each end of each pipe it creates.  It will never see EOF on `pipefd[num_processes + i][0]` as long as it has `pipefd[num_processes + i][1]` open, no matter what the child does.

As a best practice for working with pipes, each process involved should close each pipe end as soon as it no longer has need to hold it open.  Especially the write ends, as failing to close those is prone to getting you into deeper trouble, but leaving the read ends open can produce a resource leak, and that can bite you, too.

Comment: I added the line in child process `close(pipefd[num_processes + i][1]);` But still it hangs. This should have caused the read in parent to exit the while loop.

Comment: As this answer already says, @MonuDidi, the parent is blocking because it, *the parent*, is holding the write end of the pipe open.  It is not sufficient for only the child to close it, and the child will anyway close its copy automatically when it terminates.

Comment: Thanks I made it work. But I have 2 doubts 1. `If you close the write end of a pipe could you still read from it` 2. `you mentioned that parent is holding the write end, Is it because there is call to read() in parent ?`

Comment: @MonuDidi, (1) Yes. But also, a key point that it seems you still might not be grasping is that each underlying pipe end remains open until *all handles* on it are closed.  Forking creates an additional copy of every open handle of the parent.  (2) No.  It is because the parent opened both ends of the pipe (via `pipe()`) and did not close its copy of the write end. "Holds open" == "does not close".

Comment: okay. So handles are a different concept here. Multiple handles could be associated with same pipe which is nothing but a read/write end pair. So when I do close(pipfd[x][1]) from parent I am only closing the write end for parent handle. The child handle also has a copy of the pipe. Since it's not closed the write end. The write end of the pipe still remains open. So what I understand is the pipe is unique but multiple handles get associated with it and as per the protocol an end remains open until all the handles associated with the pipe closes it.

Comment: `Is there a way to see the handles where are they stored ?` Also if the parent after creating pipe() closes one write end before forking. In this case will the child also get automatically the pipe write end as closed ? This stuff is really messy. It will take time to get my head around it. Is there a good reference to learn all this type of things.

Comment: @MonuDidi, the underlying Unix concept here is that of the "open file description".  These live in the kernel.  Associated with each open file description there are one or more "handles", as POSIX puts it, which are either `FILE` objects such as `fopen()` creates or integer file descriptor values such as `open()` (or `pipe()`) returns.  Through `dup()`, `fork()`, and probably other means, it is possible to have multiple handles on the same open file description in one or more processes.  The open file description does not belong specifically to any process, and it is not copied.

Comment: Userspace processes operate with and on these handles.  Closing one disassociates it from its open file description.  The kernel closes an open file description when and only when there ceases to be any handle associated with it.  So yes, the pipe is unique, but after the `fork()` there are multiple handles on each end, and each end remains open while any handles on it remain. And yes, if the parent closes the only handle on the write end before forking then the child will not inherit any open handle on that end.